# How to add / remove different class instances from arrayList stored inside a mulitidimentional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

My overall thought process may be off here so if there is a more logical solution to this feel free to suggest. The problem is this, I have a 2 dimensional array that I am treating as an x,y grid system. I would like to be able to store multiple class instances inside a single array index. my thought was to instead store an array list inside each array index as a sort of container for the objects. The problem is that I'm not sure how to address the list that is inside a given index at array[i][j].

One solution I considered is to create a templist and set tempList = array[i][j] edit tempList set array[i][j] = tempList. Sort of a switcheroo. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried your suggested approach? What were the troubles you had with it, if any?

Comment: The array[i][j] will be a reference to the list object. The set array[i][j] = tempList is unnecessary, since they are both references to the same object. There is no copying of the list object happening. 
I think maybe you are misunderstanding the concept of references to objects.  
Also, the array will be an array of references which by default will not point to anything. You will need to check whether the reference is null, and if so, instantiate the list object lazily.

Comment: @Darren thanks for the quick response, could you propose how you would approach the problem then? I thought an array[][] would be a good parent container because I wanted it to be a fixed width and height, and I want to have arrayLists inside each of those indexes so I can freely add/remove various objects due to the added functionality of lists vs arrays. How would you approach this problem? 

Erwin that solution seems roundabout. I'm trying to adopt better practices and wanted to know if there is more efficient solution.

Comment: if your objects fall in the same hierarchy you can try something like this ~~~ List<List<? super ObjectAtTheBottomOfHierarchy>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ObjectAtTheBottomOfHierarchy>>()

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the lists directly, without any need for temporary variables.

To set a list:

```
array[0][0] = new ArrayList<>();
```

So you can fill the entire array with something along these lines:

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

List[][] array = new List[width][height];

 for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
     for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
         array[x][y] = new ArrayList<Object>();
   }
}
```

The array will have all it's elements set to `null` by default, so you will have to create a list at every index.

The above code will create an ArrayList at every position in the array, which you can then use just like any other list:

```
 array[0][0].add(element); //Adds the element to the list at [0,0]
 Object obj = array[0][0].get(0); //Gets the element we just added
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton.